# Matrix similar to its negative

Tags: direct-sum, similar-matrices

> Let $V$ denote a nonzero finite-dimensional vector space over the complex field $\mathbb{C}$. Given a linear transformation $A:V\rightarrow V$, show that i) implies ii):
>
> i) There exists an invertible linear transformation $P:V\rightarrow V$ such that $AP=-PA$
>
> ii) There exists a direct sum decomposition $V=V_1\oplus V_2$ s.t. $AV_1\subset V_2$ and $AV_2\subset V_1$.

Eigenvalues of $A$ are $\pm$ pairs.

$V_1$ and $V_2$, in particular their bases, are probably to be guessed.

Please give a hint. Please do not give solution. Thanks!

Comment: Let $Av_+=\lambda v_+$ and $Av_-=-\lambda v_-$, and consider $v_++v_-$ and $v_+-v_-$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson thanks.

Comment: If $A^kv=0$ for some positive integer $k$, consider the images of $v$ under the even powers of $A$ and the images of $v$ under the odd powers of $A$.

Comment: @user1551 Ok nice. But that's not the case here.

Comment: Why not? Every nilpotent linear operator on $V$ is similar to its negative.

Comment: @user1551 $A^kv=0$ implies $0$ is eigenvalue of $A^k$ hence of $A$. $ A = \left(\begin{matrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 \end{matrix} \right) $ satisfies the hypothesis but does not satisfy your condition.

Comment: Sigh. The Jordan form of $A$ is a direct sum of an invertible Jordan form and a nilpotent Jordan form. Gerry Myerson's hint deals with the invertible Jordan form and mine deals with the nilpotent Jordan form. You **need** to consider the nilpotent case because it is a possible case of $A$.